# How to avoid multiple queries in one execute call

Tags: python, cursor, psycopg2

I've just realized that `psycopg2` allows multiple queries in one `execute` call.

For instance, this code will actually insert two rows in `my_table`:

```
>>> import psycopg2
>>> connection = psycopg2.connection(database='testing')
>>> cursor = connection.cursor()
>>> sql = ('INSERT INTO my_table VALUES (1, 2);'
...        'INSERT INTO my_table VALUES (3, 4)')
>>> cursor.execute(sql)
>>> connection.commit()
```

Does `psycopg2` have some way of disabling this functionality? Or is there some other way to prevent this from happening?

What I've come so far is to search if the query has any semicolon (`;`) on it:

```
if ';' in sql:
    # Multiple queries not allowed!
```

But this solution is not perfect, because it wouldn't allow some valid queries like:

```
SELECT * FROM my_table WHERE name LIKE '%;'
```

---

**EDIT:** SQL injection attacks are not an issue here. I do want to give to the user full access of the database (he can even delete the whole database if he wants).

Comment: Are you trying to restrict user-supplied SQL? If so, it would be better to use parametrized SQL. I could elaborate if this is indeed your situation.

Comment: It's [safer](http://xkcd.com/327/), simpler, cleaner, and more efficient to compile `INSERT INTO my_table VALUES (%s, %s)` once as a static statement, and call `execute` (or `executemany`) with the user-supplied data than to build, compile, and run separate statements for each input.

Comment: @juliomalegria I'm afraid `psycopg2` doesn't check if there are multiple queries passed.

Comment: @abarnert `INSERT INTO` was just an example. I'm trying to find a solution that works for any kind of query

Comment: @unutbu I don't know what you mean with "parametrized SQL". But if it solves the problem (without involving the user), it may be the solution!

Comment: @juliomalegria: It doesn't matter what the query is; you want to make the queries as static as possible and use parameters (the `%s` in my example) for each set of values—`VALUES (%s)`, `WHERE foo=%s`, `SET spam=%s`, whatever.

Comment: @juliomalegria: In that case, why do you want to restrict the user from running multiple queries? What's the actual benefit you're trying to get here? If we knew that, we might be able to suggest options.

Answer (score 1):

If you want a general solution to this kind of problem, the answer is always going to be "parse format X, or at least parse it well enough to handle your needs".

In this case, it's probably pretty simple. PostgreSQL doesn't allow semicolons in the middle of column or table names, etc.; the only places they can appear are inside strings, or as statement terminators. So, you don't need a full parser, just one that can handle strings.

Unfortunately, even that isn't completely trivial, because you have to know the rules for what counts as a string literal in PostgreSQL. For example, is `"abc\"def"` a string `abc"def`?

But once you write or find a parser that can identify strings in PostgreSQL, it's easy: skip all the strings, then see if there are any semicolons left over.

For example (this is probably *not* the correct logic,* and it's also written in a verbose and inefficient way, just to show you the idea):

```
def skip_quotes(sql):
    in_1, in_2 = False, False
    for c in sql:
        if in_1:
            if c == "'":
                in_1 = False
        elif in_2:
            if c == '"':
                in_2 = False
        else:
            if c == "'":
                in_1 = True
            elif c == '"':
                in_2 = True
            else:
                yield c
```

Then you can just write:

```
if ';' in skip_quotes(sql):
    # Multiple queries not allowed!
```

---

If you can't find a pre-made parser, the first things to consider are:

- If it's so trivial that simple string operations like `find` will work, do that.
- If it's a simple, regular language, use `re`.
- If the logic can be explained descriptively (e.g., via a BNF grammar), use a parsing library or parser-generator library like [pyparsing](http://pyparsing.wikispaces.com) or [pybison](http://freenet.mcnabhosting.com/python/pybison/).
- Otherwise, you will probably need to write a state machine, or even explicit iterative code (like my example above). But this is very rarely the best answer for anything but teaching purposes.

---

* This is correct for a dialect that accepts either single- or double-quoted strings, does not escape one quote type within the other, and escapes quotes by doubling them (we will incorrectly treat `'abc''def'` as two strings `abc` and `def`, rather than one string `abc'def`, but since all we're doing is skipping the strings anyway, we get the right result), but does not have C-style backslash escapes or anything else. I believe this matches sqlite3 as it actually works, although not sqlite3 as it's documented, and I have no idea whether it matches PostgreSQL.

Answer (score 0):

Allowing users to make arbitrary queries (even single queries) can open your program up to [SQL injection attacks](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection) and [denial-of-service (DOS) attacks](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Denial-of-service_attacks). The safest way to deal with potentially malicious users is to enumerate exactly what what queries are allowable and only allow the user to supply parameter values, not the entire SQL query itself.

So for example, you could define

```
sql = 'INSERT INTO my_table VALUES (%s, %s)'
args = [1, 2]  # <-- Supplied by the user
```

and then safely execute the INSERT statement with:

```
cursor.execute(sql, args)
```

This is called [**parametrized SQL**](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2005/04/give-me-parameterized-sql-or-give-me-death.html) because the sql uses `%s` as parameter placemarkers, and the `cursor.execute` statement takes two arguments. The second argument is expected to be a sequence, and the database driver (e.g. psycopg2) will replace the parameter placemarkers with propertly quoted values supplied by `args`.

This will prevent SQL injection attacks. 
The onus is still on you (when you write your allowable SQL) to prevent denial-of-service attacks. You can attempt to protect yourself from DOS attacks by making sure the arguments supplied by the user is in a reasonable range, for instance.

Comment: Note that using `?` for the parameters is sqlite3-specific; pyscopg2 uses `%s` instead. (But since this whole answer turns out not to be relevant to the OP's actual problem, now that he's partially explained it, that probably isn't a big deal anyway.)